# Why does camel move file with only partial data?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, camel-ftp, camel-sql, camel-file

Below is my code:

```
from("quartz2:report?cron=" + cronExpression)
.routeId("jms:queue:test")
.setHeader("CURRENT_TIME", simple("${date:now:MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss.S}"))     
        //Writing column names for report to the file
        .setBody()
        .simple(summaryHeaders)
        .transform(body().append("\n"))
        .to("file:" + filePath + "?fileName="+scheduledFileName+"${date:now:MM-dd-YYYY}.csv&fileExist=append")
.to("sql:" + dataSummaryQuery + "?dataSource=#dataSource")
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Summary query executed")
        .marshal(csvFormat)
        .to("file:" + filePath + "?fileName="+scheduledFileName+"${date:now:MM-dd-YYYY}.csv&fileExist=append")
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Report written to file")
.setBody()
        .simple(fileHeaders)
        .transform(body().append("\n"))
        .to("file:" + filePath + "?fileName="+scheduledFileName+"${date:now:MM-dd-YYYY}.csv&fileExist=append")

        .to("sql:" + dataExtractionQuery + "?dataSource=#dataSource")
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "data query executed")
        .marshal(csvFormat)

        .to("file:" + filePath + "?fileName="+scheduledFileName+"${date:now:MM-dd-YYYY}.csv&fileExist=append");
```

Till the above code, everything is work fine and all the required data is in the file. When I try to move the file to a different location, the moved file only has the data from the dataextractionquery above. The previous data are not in the file. What is happening here? How can I move the file with all the data added?

Code to move the file:

```
from("file:" + filePath + "?fileName="+scheduledFileName+"${date:now:MM-dd-YYYY}.csv&fileExist=append")
        .to("file:" + filePath + "?fileName=temp/");
```

If I do not move the file, I have all the data in the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is happening here?**

The second route's performing

1. file consumer scan source file every 500 ms (default `delay` value is `500`)
2. file producer overwrite target file (default `fileExist` value is `Override`)
3. [Async to above step] file consumer move the file to `.camel` sub-folder relative to source directory (default `move` setting)

> **[MOVE AND DELETE OPERATIONS](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.4.x/file-component.html#_move_and_delete_operations)**
>
> By default, Camel will move consumed files to the .camel sub-folder
> relative to the directory where the file was consumed.

Whenever some part of data is stream to source, the route consumed it, overwrite target file (with the data in source) and then throw it away. At last, the route got last part of data and write it to target location.

**How can I move the file with all the data added?**

There is a warning ([Avoid reading files currently being written by another application](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.4.x/file-component.html#_uri_format)) and a [section](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.4.x/file-component.html#File2-Consumingfilesfromfolderswhereothersdropfilesdirectly) cover this. List some possible method for your reference.

1. Use `doneFileName` (check [USING DONE FILES](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.4.x/file-component.html#_using_done_files) and [WRITING DONE FILES](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.4.x/file-component.html#_writing_done_files))
2. Set sufficient large value for `delay`
3. Use `readLock`
4. Stop `move` by `noop` and control `idempotent` behavior by `idempotentKey` ([set with name and size](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.4.x/file-component.html#_avoiding_reading_the_same_file_more_than_once_idempotent_consumer))